# Removing Blank Columns from an excel file

Tags: python-3.x

I have written a program to download data from an API, and parse the json response into an excel (xlsx) sheet in multiple worksheets.

However, depending on user's choice on what attributes to be saved, there can be empty columns in the excel. Is there any way to delete empty columns from all worksheets in the excel file?

I can do this through pandas, however, that is not possible in this case, as pandas and openpyxl library breaks the GUI based on the python script?

Is there any other way to implement this?

Edit:

Current Output:

```
+----------+----------+--+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |  | Column D | Column E |
+----------+----------+--+----------+----------+
| A1       | B1       |  | D1       |          |
| A2       |          |  | D2       |          |
| A3       | B3       |  |          | E3       |
+----------+----------+--+----------+----------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B | Column D | Column E |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| A1       | B1       | D1       |          |
| A2       |          | D2       |          |
| A3       | B3       |          | E3       |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

Current Code for removing blank columns:

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(path, engine='openpyxl')
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file,header=None, sheet_name=None)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(finalpath,engine='openpyxl') 
for key in df:
    sheet= df[key].dropna(how="all").dropna(1,how="all")
    sheet.to_excel(writer, key,index=False, header=False )
writer.save()
```

Need to replace this code with something which don't references pandas library.

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example of the input and of the desired output, along with your current code? This would increase the chances to get a good answer.

Comment: Edited the question with more details.

Comment: Have you tried [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable)? [Here](https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/) a guide to read and save Excel files with `openpyxl`: it is quite simple.

Comment: I am using openpyxl as engine for dealing with the excel file in my current code. Pandas and openpyxl form a recursive loop while generating the exe file with pyinstaller, and are breaking the executable.

Comment: Have you tried to change engine? Using `xlsxwriter` or `xlrd` for example? Moreover, if you use only `openpyxl`, you can remove `pandas` as dependency (if it is not used elsewhere), maybe solving the recursive loop you are experimenting.

Comment: xlsxwriter fails in this case, as xlsxwriter can't modify an existing excel file.

Comment: xlrd can't handle xlsx files, and openpyxl and pandas both break the executable. Is there any alternative library that can read and modify existing xlsx files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226965/discussion-between-piecot-and-abhinav-dhiman).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a workaround, to convert xlsx files to xls files first, and then used xlrd to remove empty columns.